# Propagation types

Tags: spring, transactions

I try to use different types of propagation:

```
 <tx:advice id="txAdvice">
     <tx:attributes>
         <tx:method name="*" propagation="SUPPORTS"/>
     </tx:attributes>
 </tx:advice>
```

Next time I try propagation="MANDATORY"

Also I add println method to my doInTransaction method:

```
        txTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void doInTransaction(TransactionStatus txStatus) {
            try {
            *********************   
                                  List<Map<String, Object>> rows = dbConn.queryForList(sql, bindValues);
            ***************************
                    System.out.println(txStatus.toString());
                    System.out.println(txStatus.isNewTransaction());
                    System.out.println(txStatus.isRollbackOnly());
                }
            }catch (RuntimeException e) {
                txStatus.setRollbackOnly();
                throw e;
            }
```

And the result is simillar for Supports and Mandatory propagetion^ new value of txStatus, it show me that this is new transaction every time.

May be it doesn't use my tx advice?

```
private TransactionTemplate txTemplate;

@Autowired
private SimpleJdbcOperations dbConn;

 @Autowired
public TQuestionsRequestJDBC(PlatformTransactionManager txManager) {
    super();
    txTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(txManager);
}


 <!-- database connection -->
 <bean id ="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
     <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
     <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.12.141.1:3306/osapp?characterEncoding=UTF-8"/>
     <property name="username" value="lm"/>
     <property name="password" value="mlesia14"/>
     <property name="initialSize" value="5"/>
     <property name="maxActive" value="10"/>
 </bean>

 <bean id="jdbcConnection" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate">
     <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
 </bean>

 <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
     <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
 </bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try today with propagation="MANDATORY" and it throws exception every time - because it is no current transaction. But it works good with propagation="REQUIRED". So my problem was in me.